# Root Test Succeeds, yet the series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please have a look at the following proof I have been working on. I seemed to be getting different results when I use the root test vs the first principle. Please advise where I made mistake.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the limit.  $n$ is a dummy variable...it makes no sense to take a limit as $n\to \infty$.  I don't know what is intended.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N (\cdots)$ ?  That would make sense (so you are just asking about the convergence of the infinite series inside your limit).  That's what you appear to be analyzing.

Comment: Did you mean $$ \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k-1}{2k} \,?$$

Comment: $(2n-1)/(2n)\rightarrow 1$. The root test inconclusive.

Comment: Your first argument appears to be flawed.  Recall that $a_n<b_n$ does not imply that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n<\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$.  Take $a_n=1-\frac 1n,b_n=1$ for example.

Comment: @lulu yes. that only implies $\lim a_n\leq \lim b_n$

Comment: Your error in the Root Test is the last step, where you have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {n(2n-1)}{n(2n)}<1,$ which is false. The limit is $1$......BTW for the Root Test to succeed it is not necessary that $(|a_n|^{1/n})_n$ converges . It suffices that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m\geq n}|a_m|^{1/m}<1.$.....BTW . Nice work in the second part, where you correctly proved divergence.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for pointing out that Recall that an<bnan<bn does not imply that lim n→∞an<lim n→∞bnlimn→∞an<limn→∞bn. I think that is the mistake I made. The limit will be less than equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, everyone. I understand where I made the mistake now. Please see the snapshots below for the errors and the correct solution.

[Errors in the original solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a9m1.jpg)

[Solved problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaiuv.png)